# Docking in winform selenium instance instead of cefsharp

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cefsharp

I'm having an issue that i cannot seem to solve, i have Google'd but the same questions seem to be coming up that does not solve the issue or at least i don't understand.

I have docked `cefsharp` in to a `WinForms` panel, and can inject javascript to input data into form fields, but i liked the selenium commands better.

All i'm trying to do is dock the Selenium brower in the `Winforms` app like i did with `cefsharp` but the command line console and browser loads independantly without being docked in the winform.

**My code:** - On form browser Load.

```
        private static ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

        public FormBrowser(string[] sitesList, string mode, FormMain formMain, Project _project, Func<string, Tuple<string, string, string>> getUserPassEmail)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bool proxyUsed = false;

            CefSharpSettings.SubprocessExitIfParentProcessClosed = true;
            if (!Cef.IsInitialized) // Check before Initialized.
            {
                // Init CEF.
                CefSettings settings = new CefSettings
                {
                    CachePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"cache"),
                    UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36",
                    LogFile = @"logs\browser.log",
                    WindowlessRenderingEnabled = true,
                    MultiThreadedMessageLoop = true,
                    BrowserSubprocessPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe"),
                    LogSeverity = LogSeverity.Error
                };

                if (_project.Proxy != "ip:port")
                {
                    settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", _project.Proxy);
                    proxyUsed = true;
                }

                Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();
                Cef.Initialize(settings);
            }
            // Init CEF.

            // Init Selenium.
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
            options.AddArgument("--log-level=3");
            options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
            options.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
            options.AddArgument("remote-debugging-port=9222");
            options.BinaryLocation = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe");
            ChromeDriver _driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options)
            {
                Url = "https://www.google.com/"
            };
            // Init Selenium.

            _sitesToProcess = sitesList; // Array of sites [ url1.com , url2.com ] etc.
            _modeToUse = mode;           // Mode either [REG] or [LAP].
            _formMain = formMain;        // Main UI object.

            string _mode = _modeToUse == "MODE_REG" ? "-[REG]" : "-[LAP]";

            try
            {
                browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com/");

                string[] _macroCode = File.ReadAllLines(@"engines\" + _sitesToProcess[0] + _mode);

                InitializeChromeBrowserAsync(_mode, _macroCode, _sitesToProcess[0], _project, getUserPassEmail, proxyUsed);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Helpers.DebugLogging($"[{DateTime.Now}]-[{ex}]");
            }
        }
```

Then in `InitializeChromeBrowserAsync`

```
        private async void InitializeChromeBrowserAsync(string _macroModeToUse, string[] _macroCode, string _site, Project _project, Func<string, Tuple<string, string, string>> getUserPassEmail, bool proxyUsed)
        {
            try
            {
                await ExcecuteMacroCode(_macroModeToUse, _macroCode, _site, _project, getUserPassEmail, proxyUsed);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Helpers.DebugLogging($"[{DateTime.Now}]-[{ex}]");
            }
        }
```

Goes to `ExcecuteMacroCode`

```
        public async Task ExcecuteMacroCode(string _macroModeToUse, string[] _macroCode, string _site, Project _project, Func<string, Tuple<string, string, string>> _getUserPassEmail, bool _proxyUsed)
        {
            var theProxy = _proxyUsed == true ? _project.Proxy : "NO_PROXY";
            Log.Add("Proxy used: " + theProxy);

            try
            {
                if (_macroModeToUse == "-[REG]")
                {
                    foreach (string _macroCodeFile in _macroCode)
                    {
                        string[] code = _macroCodeFile.Split('|');

                        // Sometimes a row might have 3 sections, account for this.
                        string theThirdValue = null;
                        if (code.Length > 2)
                        {
                            theThirdValue = code[2];
                        }

                        switch (code[0])
                        {
                            case "RJ_U":
                                string cleanUrl = code[1].Replace("{HOSTNAME}", _site);
                                browser.Load(cleanUrl);
                                panelBrowserMain.Controls.Add(browser);
                                browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                                browserMain.Text = cleanUrl;
                                browser.FrameLoadEnd += Browser_FrameLoadEnd;
                                browser.AddressChanged += Browser_AddressChanged;
                                await Task.Delay(int.Parse(_formMain.ComboBoxPauseInSeconds.Text + "000"));
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Helpers.DebugLogging($"[{DateTime.Now}]-[{ex}]");
            }
        }
```

I have taken out a lot of the code to keep it as relevant as possible, this part `case "RJ_U":` is where we goto that URL via cefsharp.

What i'm asking is how can i dock the selenium browser instance so i can use selenium commands? or is that not possible?

In this example with Java: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/UsingChromeDriver

I don't see how it's docked in the winform. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You say selenium instead of CefSharp, what browser are you planning on using? Question could use some clarification.

Answer (score -2):

Try using if-elseif statement instead of switch-case statement. Switch statement can have some problem with async-await.

Check the await Task.delay & int.parse once.